# why does rust allow comparison between &String and string slice?

Tags: string, rust

```
fn main() {
    println!("hello hello");
    let s = String::from("something");
    assert_eq!(&s, "something");
    println!("able to compare &String with a string slice");
}

Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.03s
     Running `target/debug/SomePrototype`
hello hello
able to compare &String with a string slice`
```

why does the above code work? how is rust compiler able to compare &String with a string slice?

Comment: I suspect the type of "something" is not a slice. in fact it is &String, so we're not actually comparing &String with a slice.

Comment: I see, how can I know more about deref coercion? can you please point me to any documentation which helps me understand more about it?

Comment: @PitaJ This is not related to deref coercion, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [`PartialEq<str>` is implemented for `String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.68.0/src/alloc/string.rs.html#2252), so you can compare `String` with `str`, and [there is a blanket implementation `<A: PartialEq<B>> PartialEq<&B> for &A`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.68.0/src/core/cmp.rs.html#1525-1537), so you can also compare `&String` with `&str`.

This is **not** related to deref coercion, as it does not apply to operators.